# Собрать array в implode или как бы поступить правильней

Tags: php

Такой кусочек кода (работает для моей задачи прекрасно)

```
$handle = fopen("convertcsv.csv", "r");
$row = 1;
$tovar = array();

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
    array_shift($delimiters);
    if($delimiters != NULL) {
        foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
            $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
        }
    }
    return  $ary;
}
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";",'"','"')) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    foreach($data as $a_product) {
        $tovar['_ID_'] =  $data[0];

        $string = $data[16];
        $delimiters = Array("|",":");
        $tovar['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = multiexplode($delimiters,$string);


    }
    $articles[] = $tovar;

    $row++;
}
```

Вот что получаю на выходе (вырезал из центра( так что не смотрите что 26,27))

```
[26] => Array
    (
        [_ID_] => 41576
        [_ATTRIBUTES_] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Длина
                        [1] =>  310 мм
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Ширина
                        [1] =>  310 мм
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Видеокамера
                        [1] =>  Есть 
                    )

            )

    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [_ID_] => 41565
        [_ATTRIBUTES_] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Наличие GPS
                        [1] =>  Нет 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Автопилот
                        [1] =>  Нет 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Время полёта
                        [1] =>  10-15 мин
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Длина
                        [1] =>  580 мм
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Ширина
                        [1] =>  560 мм
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Видеокамера
                        [1] =>  Нет 
                    )

            )

    )
```

И мне нужно это собрать так в блоке *ATTRIBUTES*

**"Характеристика|Длина|310 мм".PHP_EOL
"Характеристика|Ширина|310 мм".PHP_EOL
**
Ну и так далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно только строковое представление атрибутов, то замените

```
$tovar['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = multiexplode($delimiters,$string);
```

на

```
$tovar['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = '';
$attributes = multiexplode($delimiters,$string);
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    list($attributeName, $attributeVal) = $attribute;
    $tovar['_ATTRIBUTES_'] .= "Характеристика|{$attributeName}|{$attributeVal}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Или (что возможно правильнее) заведите функцию вроде такой:

```
function attributesToStr($attributes) {
    $attributesStr = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        list($attributeName, $attributeVal) = $attribute;
        $attributesStr .= "Характеристика|{$attributeName}|{$attributeVal}" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    return $attributesStr;
}
```

И при необходимости обходите товары с помощью `foreach` и скармливайте ей их атрибуты.

Answer (score 1):

Не самое лучшее решение (из-за кол-ва циклов):

```
foreach($array as $v){
    foreach($v["_ATTRIBUTES_"] as $attribute){
        foreach($attribute as $k=>$a){
            $final[]="{$k}||{$a}";
            unset($k,$a);
        }
        unset($attribute);
    }
    unset($v);
}
```

Comment: Не могу понять как внедрить к себе в код

Comment: Надо полагать Вы предоставили дамп массива `$articles`? Данные циклы нужно запустить после получения этого массива, после Вашего while.